# User Control as DataType in Umbraco

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco6

i am using umbraco with MVC and trying to use asp.net userControl as datatype by following a post [Click here for post i followed](http://oshyn.com/_blog/Web_Content_Management/post/Custom_DataTypes_in_Umbraco/) but in my case onchange event of radio buttons are not called might be the situation is that i am using umbraco mvc so it did not support postback events. if my above reason is correct then what is the other way to create same functionality datatype in my case.
i have binged and googled it but still no useful hint.

i want ui of my field like that at one time just one control should be visible either file loader or textbox(multiline). i can achieve this hide and visible by jquery but unable to get values of controls on it.
[image]

any help please ......

Answer (score 2):

Judging on your screenshot you are still using umbraco 4 or 6.

What you are trying to archive, should be no problem at all.  It has nothing to do with the MVC part of the front end.

The reason why the buttons are not triggering "onchange" is probably because you are missing a "autopostback" on the radio button.

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1"  
  runat="server"  
  Text="radio button 1"  
  GroupName="group1"  
  AutoPostBack="True"
  Checked="True" />
```